# customize window.print() in drupal block

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I have used a block for adding an option to print the page.The content of the block is 
`<a onclick='window.print();' style='cursor:pointer'>Print this page</a>`

It works fine but I need to customize the content to be printed.How can this be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize what gets printed and how printed content looks like using media specific CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
h1 { text-align: center }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot customize window.print(). It will print the focusing window. If you need to customize the print area, then the elements to be printed should be added in a separate window.

For more info visit [here](http://drupaltroll.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/custom-print-function-using-javascript/)